# XYZ to a linear value and vice-versa

Tags: arrays, c, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I have my 3D world `x, y, z`. I can easily convert given coordinates `x`, `y`, `z` to an integer using my macro `XYZ`:

```
const ulong WORLD_SIZE_X = 60;
const ulong WORLD_SIZE_Y = 60;
const ulong WORLD_SIZE_Z = 60;
const ulong WORLD_SIZE = WORLD_SIZE_X * WORLD_SIZE_Y * WORLD_SIZE_Z;
#define XYZ(_x, _y, _z) \
    ((_x) + ((_y)*WORLD_SIZE_X) + ((_z)*WORLD_SIZE_X*WORLD_SIZE_Y))
```

Hence I can allocate a big "linear" array via `calloc(WORLD_SIZE, sizeof(Cube))`, and I can access to any cube like this (just an example):

```
for (int z=0; z<=WORLD_SIZE_Z; ++z) {
    for (int y=0; y<=WORLD_SIZE_Y; ++y) {
        for (int x=0; x<=WORLD_SIZE_X; ++x) {
            printf("blabla\n", myWorld(XYZ(x, y, z));
        }
    }
}
```

So:

- I can allocate a "linear" array (= much simpler for me than array of array of array)
- given `x`, `y` and `z`, I can easily find the element I want

And I cant find the right macro that do the opposite: given a `long long pos`, find `x`, `y` and `z`.

For a 2D array it's simple, it's `x = pos % SIZE_X;` and `y = (int)(pos / SIZE_X);`. But for a 3D world how do you do?

Comment: Using a `struct` with `.x`, `.y` and `.z` members would make things much simpler.

Comment: this means allocate for each struct 3 "unsigned long" *more*? (I have already a `Cube` struct that contains the type of link to north/south/east/west/front/back).

Comment: If your ranges are such that all three will fit into a single `ulong`, then each member (probably) need  only be a single `ubyte` (or whatever its called in your naming system). That way, with padding, the `struct` size will be the same as a single `ulong`. And access will be faster, because maths isn't involved, in either direction.

Comment: What are the valid/possible ranges of `(x, y, z)`, Min & Max values in each dimension?

Comment: It goes from 0 -> WORLD_SIZE_[X/Y/Z]

Comment: What's the possible maximum value `WORLD_SIZE_[X/Y/Z]` can take in your project scope? Just for memory allocation this is a tedious convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it is easier if you rewrite your equation:

```
u = (z * WORLD_SIZE_Y + y) * WORLD_SIZE_X + x;
```

You can get the individual coordinates with:

```
x = u % WORLD_SIZE_X;
y = (u / WORLD_SIZE_X) % WORLD_SIZE_Y;
z = (u / WORLD_SIZE_X) / WORLD_SIZE_Y;
```

Comment: Is the order of `%` and `/` important? I just found that this works for me, given that: `WORLD_SIZE_XY = WORLD_SIZE_X * WORLD_SIZE_Y`: `x = u % WORLD_SIZE_X;  y = (u % WORLD_SIZE_XY) / WORLD_SIZE_X; z = i / WORLD_SIZE_XY;`

Comment: You solution works, too.

Comment: You can do it either way. (In my code above, the brackets are not really necessary.) This is a bit like extracting the tens digit from a number: You can use `(n / 10) % 10` or `(n % 100) / 10`.

Answer (score 2):

The expressions to 'extract' the X, Y and Z ordinates from the combined `pos` need to reverse the operations that are used to form that position.

- For X, it will be the same as the 2D case (just taking the value modulo X_SIZE):
  `x = pos % X_SIZE`.
- For Y, we can first divide by X_SIZE (to shift-out the X component), then take the result modulo Y_SIZE:
  `y = (pos / X_SIZE) % Y_SIZE`.
- For Z, we extend your original operation for the 2D Y, but divide by the product of X_SIZE and Y_SIZE:
  `z = pos / (X_SIZE * Y_SIZE)`

However, your system would likely be more efficient (avoiding any maths) by defining a `struct` for the position; assuming the three "world dimensions" will be no greater than 255, we can use single bytes for each element. You can then have an array (1D) of such structures, and can assign all three (x, y, and z) values in one statement – *without using macros* – by means of a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

Here's a brief demo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    uint8_t x;
    uint8_t y;
    uint8_t z;
} pos_type;

int main()
{
    uint8_t x = 37;
    uint8_t y = 42;
    uint8_t z = 123;
    pos_type pos[100];
    pos[3] = (pos_type){ x, y, z }; // Can assign elements using a compound literal
    uint8_t ax = pos[3].x;
    uint8_t ay = pos[3].y;
    uint8_t az = pos[3].z;
    printf("%hhu %hhu %hhu\n", ax, ay, az);
    return 0;
}
```